# Term for a "Special Identifier" Embedded in String Data

Tags: json, string, parsing

I'm mostly at a loss for how to describe this, so I'll start with a simple example that is similar to some JSON I'm working with:

```
"user_interface": {
    username: "Hello, %USER.username%",
    create_date: "Your account was created on %USER.create_date%",
    favorite_color: "Your favorite color is: %USER.fav_color%"
}
```

The "special identifiers" located in the `username` `create_date` and `favorite_color` fields start and end with `%` characters, and are supposed to be replaced with the correct information for that particular user. An example for the `favorite_color` field would be:

`Your favorite color is: Orange`

Is there a proper term for these identifiers? I'm trying to search google for best practices or libraries when parsing these before I reinvent the wheel, but everything I can think of results in a sea of false-positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some thoughts on the subject of `%special identifier%`. Let's take a look at a small subset of examples, that implement almost similar strings replacement.

**[WSH Shell ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf.aspx)**

> Returns an **environment variable**'s expanded value.

WSH .vbs code snippet

```vb
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("WinDir is %WinDir%")
' WinDir is C:\Windows
```

**[.NET Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)**

> The .NET Framework composite formatting feature takes a list of objects and a composite format string as input. A composite format string consists of fixed text intermixed with indexed placeholders, called **format items**, that correspond to the objects in the list. The formatting operation yields a result string that consists of the original fixed text intermixed with the string representation of the objects in the list.

VB.Net code snippet

```vb
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Prime numbers less than 10: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 ))
' Prime numbers less than 10: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7
```

**[JavaScript replace Method (with RegEx application)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc.aspx)**

> ... The **match variables** can be used in text replacement where the replacement string has to be determined dynamically... $n ... The nth captured submatch ...

Also called [Format Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx#formatflags), [Substitution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx), [Backreference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/43k3181w.aspx) and [Format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/)
JavaScript code snippet

```
console.log("Hello, World!".replace(/(\w+)\W+(\w+)/g, "$1, dear $2"))
// Hello, dear World!
```

**[Python Format strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)**

> Format strings contain “**replacement fields**” surrounded by curly braces {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output...

Python code snippet

```py
print "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
# The sum of 1 + 2 is 3
```

**[Ruby String Interpolation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html)**

> Double-quote strings allow **interpolation** of other values using#{...} ...

Ruby code snippet

```rb
res = 3
puts "The sum of 1 + 2 is #{res}"
# The sum of 1 + 2 is 3
```

**[TestComplete Custom String Generator](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/71861/)**

> ... A string of macros, text, format specifiers and regular expressions that will be used to generate values. The default value of this parameter is %INT(1, 2147483647, 1) %NAME(ANY, FULL) lives in %CITY. ... Also, you can format the generated values using special **format specifiers**. For instance, you can use the following macro to generate a sequence of integer values with the specified minimum length (3 characters) -- %0.3d%INT(1, 100, 3).

**[Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)**

> **Angular expressions** are JavaScript-like code snippets that are mainly placed in interpolation bindings such as{{ textBinding }}...

**[Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/)**

> **Variables** are surrounded by {{ and }} like this:
> `My first name is {{ first_name }}. My last name is {{ last_name }}.`
> With a context of {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}, this template renders to:
> `My first name is John. My last name is Doe.`

**[Node.js v4 Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)**

> ... Template strings can contain **place holders**. These are indicated by the Dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}). The expressions in the place holders and the text between them get passed to a function...

JavaScript code snippet

```
var res = 3;
console.log(`The sum of 1 + 2 is ${res}`);
// The sum of 1 + 2 is 3
```

**[C/C++ Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/503x3e3s.aspx)**

> Preprocessing expands **macros** in all lines that are not preprocessor directives...
>   Replacement in source code.

C++ code snippet

```cpp
std::cout << __DATE__;
// Jan 8 2016
```

**[AutoIt Macros](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_macros.htm)**

> AutoIt has an number of **Macros** that are special read-only variables used by AutoIt. Macros start with the @ character ...
>   Replacement in source code.

AutoIt code snippet

```
MsgBox(0, "", "CPU Architecture is " & @CPUArch)
; CPU Architecture is X64
```

**[SharePoint solution Replaceable Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545.aspx)**

> **Replaceable parameters**, or **tokens**, can be used inside project files to provide values for SharePoint solution items whose actual values are not known at design time. They are similar in function to the standard Visual Studio template tokens... Tokens begin and end with a dollar sign ($) character. Any tokens used are replaced with actual values when a project is packaged into a SharePoint solution package (.wsp) file at deployment time. For example, the token $SharePoint.Package.Name$ might resolve to the string "Test SharePoint Package."

**[Apache Ant Replace Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html)**

> Replace is a directory based task for replacing the occurrence of a given string with another string in selected file... **token**... the **token** which must be replaced...

So, based on functional context I would call it **`%token%`** (such a flavor of [strings with an identified "meaning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)).

Comment: That's quite an extensive list. Calling it `token` is probably as good as any of the others, but I'm still surprised there isn't a widely accepted term (with perhaps minor variations) considering how many languages implement some form of this. I'll see if anyone else can add input before accepting this answer.

Comment: @ChristopherSheaf Just try a simple search, eg on SO, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+replace+token), and you will see that `token` is commonly used and usually stands for that special identifier.